# add js file after login success

Tags: javascript, module, drupal-7

I want to add a file after the login success in my custom module.login page redirect to some page and need to add js file after redirection to new page in drupal.now file added before redirect to success page in drupal 7

```
one_time_popup_user_login_submit($form,$form_state){
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/celebrationPopup.js','file');
}

one_time_popup_init(){
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/celebrationPopup.js','file'); //not working
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
function Modulename_init() {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'Modulename') . '/yourjs.js');
  }
}
```

Make sure that your js file is inside your custom module

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuery try looking at [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)